# Spring Boot OAuth 2 Authorization Server JWK value is different when there are multiple instances and JWT validation at the resource server fails

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have an Authorization Server deployed in the cloud (PCF) with multiple instances. While retrieving user info (resource server), I am getting the error below. As per my observation, each instance generates a different JWK source. When the request goes to the instance where the token was generated it works fine. But when a request goes to another instance, the following error occurs:

**o.s.s.o.s.r.a.JwtAuthenticationProvider : Failed to authenticate since the JWT was invalid**

I have customized RSA keys to read from a properties file.

```
@Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt);
        return http.build();
    }


 @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }


    private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = RsaKeyProperties.getPublicKey();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = RsaKeyProperties.getPrivateKey();

        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note: Session store type is Redis

Answer (score 0):

Signature validation of access token fails if the "kid" (key identifier) in the access token header does not have a corresponding kid in the JWKS.

In your case each instance of the Auth Server is generating a new `kid` due to `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` used here. So access_token generated in one instance will fail signature validation in second instance and vice versa.

Fix for this would be to generate and inject a static UUID.

```
private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
    RSAPublicKey publicKey = RsaKeyProperties.getPublicKey();
    RSAPrivateKey privateKey = RsaKeyProperties.getPrivateKey();

    return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
            .privateKey(privateKey)
            .keyID("9a9b9b7c-33d8-40f0-bd64-d85c7a5aa33a")
            .build();
}
```

NOTE: I've only added a static id as an example here. You should ideally store this value securely and retrieve it during the startup of the Auth Server Service.